# where to put my theme in rwd package?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, design

I'm trying to override "content" block of page.xml. It works with default design package. I can output products in content block:

[image]

but with rwd package it not overriding "content":

[image]
no matter if I put my 'trening' theme in rwd or default directory:

[image]

```
#\app\code\local\Trening\NewModule\etc\config.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <newmodule>
                <class>Trening_NewModule_Model</class>
            </newmodule>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <newmodule>
                <class>Trening_NewModule_Block</class>
            </newmodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <newmodule>
                <class>Trening_NewModule_Helper</class>
            </newmodule>
        </helpers>

        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <NewModule>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>NewModule/observer</class>
                        <method>logCustomer</method>
                    </NewModule>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <trening_newmodule>
                <use>standard</use> <!--standardowy router, (nie ważne, trzeba to wpisać)-->
                <args>
                    <module>Trening_NewModule</module>
                    <frontName>trening</frontName> <!--pierwszy człon adresu url który ma prowadzić do tego modułu  localhost/trening/.../..-->
                </args>
            </trening_newmodule>
            <catalog> //nadpisanie kontrolera catalog/product
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <demo before="Mage_Catalog">Trening_NewModule</demo>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <newmodule>
                    <file>trening.xml</file>
                </newmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

How to do it to make it work in rwd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add **rwd** in Current Package Name in admin Desing tab instead of default.

You have to add **page.xml** inside `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`.

You have to remove your custom trening directory `frontend/rwd/default/trening` and move trening.xml and myproducts.phtml to respectable `rwd/layout/` and `rwd/template`directories then leave blank inputs in theme admin Desing tab **or** (better solution) move your trening directory level up to `rwd/` directory not `rwd/default/` and stay with 'trening' name in admin Design Themes Default input.

[image]

Clear cache and check.

Comment: I added  rwd in Current Package Name , check my 2nd picture. Also app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml is there by default.

Comment: have you remove var folder and clear cache.

Comment: Im working in dev mode, anyway I cleared cache and removed var dir  and still same.

Comment: have you check in backend, System -> design tab with any defau;t theme is not defined?

Comment: still the same. (if You meant to blank all inputs in them,e but package name rwd)

Comment: have you check any theme is assigned or not?

Comment: I tried with all blank inputs in theme section, and tried with 'trening' in Themes/Default as in 2nd picture.

Comment: this trenning project is in https://github.com/sruj/MagentoTrening

Comment: Got it you have keep treingin folder inside default folder it is wrong. you have to keep trening.xml file inside rwd/default/layout/trening.xml and rwd/default/template/trening/mytemplate.phtml file,